# How many left cosets of <f>=<128> are in s6?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

I'm not too sure how to try this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cosets of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called the index and written $[G : H]$. $\mid G \mid = \mid H \mid \cdot [G : H]$ is an easily proven result as each coset is of the same size as $H$.